# Is there a way to log out classes that Java attempts to load, but aren't found on the classpath?

Tags: java

I'm trying to support an old version of a Java web app that I don't have the source to. When I run this program, the log shows the following:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Error registering bean with name 'Censored' defined in ServletContext resource [
/WEB-INF/censored.xml]: Class that bean class [com.censored.Censored] depends on not found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
...
```

So I can see what class is throwing the error, but I can't see what dependency it feels is missing. Is there an argument that I can throw into Java somewhere to log out when a class is attempted to be loaded that doesn't really exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try starting the JVM using the `-verbose:class` option. That will log all class loading to the console. Maybe that gives you more information.